# Image disappeared after changing CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, image

I am using QGIS 2.10.1
Why my image disappeared after changing the CRS?

My procedure:
Project>Project properties>CRS
Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation

After I choose the desired CRS, my image is disappeared.

Comment: the image was projected to new CRS.  Set the map to **Zoom Full** or select the layer and choose **Zoom to layer**.

Comment: Please add the CRS of the **layer** and **project**, and the extent of the **layer**, as reported by rightclick on the legend entry -> Properties, Metadata tab, Properties section.

Answer (score 5):

The image was projected to new CRS. Set the map to Zoom Full or select the layer and choose Zoom to layer to see the image.